# Android database cursor.getString() crashes

Tags: android

I have a problem getting information from third column of database with getString();
When i set to get information from second column everything is working fine ,but with the third column the app crashes.
Here is the code for second column, the one that is working:

```
    Cursor data = myDB.getData();
    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    while(data.moveToNext()){
        //get the value from the database in column 1
        //then add it to the ArrayList
        listData.add(data.getString(1));
     //create the list adapter and set the adapter
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The info that is stored in this column is taken from EditText field.

And the other code that is not working:

```
    //get the data and append to a list
    Cursor data = myDB.getData();
    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        //get the value from the database in column 1
        //then add it to the ArrayList
        listData.add(data.getString(2));
    }
    //create the list adapter and set the adapter
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

What is stored in the third column is :

```
private String date;

date = getDate();

private String getDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date todayDate = new Date();
    String thisDate = currentDate.format(todayDate);
    return thisDate;
}
```

If i change the second getString(2) like getString(0) the app is working;
Thank you in advance!

Logcat error

> 07-13 15:26:15.431: W/ls(5674): type=1400 audit(0.0:301): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/ueventd.rc" dev="rootfs" ino=4003 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:rootfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 07-13 15:26:15.431: W/ls(5674): type=1400 audit(0.0:302): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/ueventd.ranchu.rc" dev="rootfs" ino=4002 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:rootfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 01-01 00:00:00.000: E/(-1): LogCat Connection error 01-01 00:00:00.000: E/(-1): Device disconnected: 1 01-01 00:00:00.000: E/(-1): Device disconnected

Comment: what is your exception? post your logat crash

Comment: 07-13 15:26:15.431: W/ls(5674): type=1400 audit(0.0:301): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/ueventd.rc" dev="rootfs" ino=4003 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:rootfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
07-13 15:26:15.431: W/ls(5674): type=1400 audit(0.0:302): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/ueventd.ranchu.rc" dev="rootfs" ino=4002 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:rootfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
01-01 00:00:00.000: E/(-1): LogCat Connection error
01-01 00:00:00.000: E/(-1): Device disconnected: 1
01-01 00:00:00.000: E/(-1): Device disconnected

Comment: These are the lines before it crashes.

Comment: Your logcat is not complete, this is saying that the device was disconnected from the computer...please look into your logcat again, and try to post the correct stacktrace (and error)

Comment: Updated my answer and this is it what i can find. Moreover, this is what i get in the console:  [2017-07-13 18:57:19 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2017-07-13 18:57:20 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2017-07-13 18:57:36 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger

Comment: Again, it's not complete. Your device is becoming disconnected